# How to close Vscode window without closing all tabs in macOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I switch between many projects, all having triple panes and many tabs open. When I'm not working on a project I close the window using the GUI by the normal red close window button. When I open it again all my tabs are as I've left.

How do I do it with a keyboard shortcut? Cmd+W closes the current tab (which I don't want), Cmd+Q quits Vscode completely (which I don't want either), closing all windows. How do I close a single Vscode window with keyboard, identical to hitting the close button with mouse, so that when I reopen the window in the future all my tabs are intact?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Mac:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Windows:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Comment: What is the command in Keyboard Shortcuts that accomplishes this? `workbench.action.closeWindow` does not seem to do it.

Comment: @GordonFogus it seems to be the macOS-native default way to close a window. If you're on macOS that seems to work out of the box. If not, your OS's "close window" keyboard shortcut might work (though I haven't tried). Not sure if it can be overridden in settings JSON.